# Uploading file array from android to $_FILES

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I want to upload few files from my android code so that it is available in the $_FILES array.

The server is looking for the files as an array. The php code in the server looks like

```
for ($i=0;$i<$NumFiles;$i++){
   ...
   $filename = $_FILES["fileset"]["name"][$i];
   $filetype = $_FILES["fileset"]["type"][$i];
   $file = curl_image_create($filePath,$filetype,$filename);
   ...
}
```

I have the files loaded in a File[] (fileSet) for my android code

```
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(this.apiURL);
        MultipartEntityBuilder mpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        StringBody numFilesBody = new StringBody("" + fileSet.length, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        mpEntity.addPart("NumFiles", numFilesBody);
        for (int i = 0; i < fileSet.length; i++) {
            //What should I be doing here to get the $_FILES set up correctly
        }
        request.setEntity(mpEntity.build());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I need to set up the HTT PRequest so that the server can read the files in the $_Files as an array.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I need to set up the HTTPRequest so that the server can read the files in the $_Files as an array

Comment: Is your `fileSet` already an array of ByteArrayBody? Or, what is the datatype  of your `fileSet` object.

Comment: fileSet is an array of File.

Comment: `for ($i=0;$i<$NumFiles;$i++)`. How did the server determine `$NumFiles? Please show exact php code.

Comment: Please do not call that fileSet as it is no Set. Very confusing. Better use File files[]; Are you forced to use that php code? If not then php code could be simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
File files [] = .....
```

Then add them in the for loop as:

```
mpEntity.addPart( "fileset[" + i + "]", new FileBody(files[i]) );
```

Comment: Thankyou for your guidance, any referral links, kindly share here.